# How can I conform to a 4 nest rule?

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, lint

I am working on some CSS, and am using GRUNT.js to lint my code. The linting rules have a 4 nest limit, how can I change the code below to conform to this rule?

```
.footer {
    .footer-tools {
        a {
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            color: $color-alpha;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-left: 48px;

            &:hover {
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            &.fill {
                .icon {
                    color: $color-horizon;
                }

                .cart-qty {
                    display: inline;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In particular it is the .icon and .cart-qty rules that are breaking the rules. If tried breaking those classes out into a seperate rule called a.fill, but the linting tool asked me to merge it with the original rule, and that puts me back to square 1 :/

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.footer`, `.footer-tools` and `a` have only one child, so you can write it in one selector `.footer .footer-tools a` and your nested level would be 3 intead of 5

Comment: Perfect thanks :) I think this was one of those scenarios where I have been looking at it so long, I couldn't see the solution properly.